# A Swift module that contains all extension methods

Tags: swift, extension-methods, rx-swift, swift-protocols

Personally, I prefer extension methods with prefix in Swift. It makes easier to guess whether a function is from the original class or from the extension at first glance. Also, it makes frameworks more reusable in other projects. We don't need to search for the namespace in which the framework method belongs. However, adding prefix to all instance and static methods in extensions is a little bit exhaustive. For this reason, I want to create a module that contains all extension methods whether it is instance or static.

I have taken a look at [this implementation](https://medium.com/@KaushElsewhere/better-way-to-manage-swift-extensions-in-ios-project-78dc34221bc8), and liked it but unfortunately it only works for instance methods:

```
public protocol MyHelperCompatible {
    associatedtype someType
    var my: someType { get }
}

public extension MyHelperCompatible {
    public var my: MyHelper<Self> {
        get { return MyHelper(self) }
    }
}

public struct MyHelper<Base> {
    let base: Base
    init(_ base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }
}

// All conformance here
extension UIColor: MyHelperCompatible { }
```

Using this, we're able to access instance methods as follows:

```
let redImage = UIColor.red.my.toImage()
```

Do you know a way to apply a similar logic to add module to handle both instance and static methods? (e.g., `UIColor.my.staticMethod()`) What way do you advise to use for this issue?

Comment: Check the RxSwift implementation of the `rx` extension.

Comment: In your example I would extend UIColor by adding method toImage(). This looks more natural to me.

Comment: About static methods: you can use them in extension as well. Just add keyword 'static'

Comment: @cyanide Of course. But what I'm trying to do is something different; calling the static extension method using a module (e.g., "my" in the example). It's useful for large frameworks. Sometimes people may forget which method belongs to the original class and which to the extension.

Comment: @Cristik It's funny that only line I need to add is "static var my: MyExtension<Self>.Type". I thought that the solution would be much more complex than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the approach RxSwift went on, here's a solution that provides access to both instance and static members of the `my` extension.

First things first, let's declare the basis for the extension:

```
struct MyExtension<Target> {
    let target: Target

    init(_ target: Target) {
        self.target = target
    }
}
```

Let's allow types to conform:

```
protocol MyExtensionCompatible { }

extension MyExtensionCompatible {
    // instance extension
    var my: MyExtension<Self> { return MyExtension(self) }

    // static extension
    static var my: MyExtension<Self>.Type { return MyExtension<Self>.self }
}
```

Now let's start playing and add the `UIColor` conformance:

```
extension UIColor: MyExtensionCompatible { }

extension MyExtension where Target == UIColor {

    static var customColor: UIColor { return UIColor.blue }

    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```

Finally, let's use everything we created above:

```
// the static property
let color = UIColor.my.customColor

// the instance function
let colorImage = color.my.toImage()

// foldoesn't compile, compile, we haven't declared UILabel as compatible
let color2 = UILabel.my
```

What's nice about the above approach is that the methods declared as static will be available via the static protocol property, while the instance ones via the instance protocol property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Only one thing is remained. What if our extension has a stored property? Since static stored properties aren't supported for generic types, we cannot achieve to call them using 'my' proxy. Do you have a solution for this as well?

Comment: @DorukhanArslan is there a use case for what you describe? The extension should not have any properties besides the target one, that's the pattern. I think you're describing something else.

Comment: I mean... A standard extension (Assume it's extension of class X) can hold stored properties. However, since we provide the access through a generic type in this approach, even if we create an extension where its target is X, we cannot define stored properties in the new extension contrary to the standard extension. It can be problematic when we try to convert our old extension to the brand-new constrained protocol extensions. Can we modify our model to solve this issue?

Comment: @DorukhanArslan extensions can't have stored properties, regardless which kind of extensions they are. That's a language design choice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about "static" stored properties.

Comment: @DorukhanArslan ok, but still, do you have a valid use case for that? If yes, then can I recommend asking another SO question on that?